# How to get input values of the 1st and Nth div below with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, serialization

`$.fn.serialize()` is close to what I want except that it only applies for `<form>`,how to do it for general `<div>` ?

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="var1" />
....
</div>

<div>
..
</dvi>

<div>
<input type="text" name="varN" />
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best answer, as [karim79](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70393/karim79) put it in a comment, is:

```
$("div:eq(0), div:eq(n)").find(":input").serialize();
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery's `.serialize()` method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is not just for forms.

**[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):**

> The `.serialize()` method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as `<input>, <textarea>, and <select>`. However, it is typically easier to select the `<form>` tag itself for serialization:

So just select the elements you want, and use `.serialize()`:

```
var ser = $('input[name=var1],input[name=varN]').serialize();
```

Comment: How to select the `:input` within the 1st and Nth `div` in my example?

Comment: You can do so like this: `$("div:eq(0), div:eq(n)").find(":input").serialize();`

Comment: @karim79: Hope you don't mind I overwrote your example. I think a couple of our edits were colliding. Thanks for the assist, though. :o)

Comment: @fms: Use @karim79's solution if you don't actually have `name` attributes on the inputs. The best selection approach will depend on your HTML.

Comment: @karim79: Yeah, I didn't think you'd take it too personally. ;o)

Comment: How to select those `:input` elements within div1~divN,where `N` is a variable?

Comment: @fms: I see you changed the accepted answer. That's fine. Just be aware that it takes into consideration the entire document. Using the `name` attribute (as provided in your HTML) selects specifically what you want, whereas your accepted answer will break if you add another `<div>` earlier in the page. Your question seemed to be more about the serialization, so I focused mainly on that. Keep in mind that if you ask a question about DOM selection, a good answer will depend heavily on the accuracy of the HTML you provide. :o)

Comment: @fms heed @patrick dw's words in this last comment! :o) Use e.g. `$("#id > div:eq(0), #id > div:eq(n)")...` to narrow the scope to `div` tags that are children of a container with `id=id`. For more info & options, see jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form, clone your divs inside that, and then call .serialize() on that new form

```
$f = $('<form/>');
$('div').each(function(i,e) {
  $f.append($(e).clone() )
})
$f.serialize();
```

But isn't it required by DTD for input to be wrapped in <form>?